# Formatar o ultimo resultado do Select Mysql diferente

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso colocar o ultimo resultado com uma formatação diferente. como em uma tabela mysql, por exemplo.

```
<a class="registro">Valor 1</a>
<a class="registro">Valor 2</a>
<a id="ultimoregistro" class="registro">Valor 3</a>
```

Gostaria de classificar o ultimo registro com uma formatação diferente do restante em PHP, como faço?.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, utilize CSS e não PHP ou MySQL... Exemplo:

```css
ul a {
  color: blue;
}

ul li:last-child a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Não é pela questão do estilo, e sim da estrutura html do ultimo item. quero que retorne diferente dos outros anteriores.

Comment: Olá, bom então é "estrutura" e não "formatação", nem consta "estrutura" na questão original... :-( "Preciso colocar o ultimo resultado com uma formatação diferente" ==> Você não precisa mudar a estrutura para fazer isso, esta é a minha dica ;-)